# Android + mysql + node.js + html + javascript - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, node.js

Is it possible to have

- html + javascript web frontend,
- node.js + mysql backend, store images to that mysql database and then have
- Android application which would download those images and save them to phone?

If it is possible, will I need some another tools than listed before?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: you want all these as separate applications or just in single android application....

Comment: I would add a javascript library like jquery to make your life a little easier and your code more cross-browser friendly.

Comment: @SLaks: I don't know if they can connect.

Comment: @Rohan: there will be web app and android app which will share data through mysql

Comment: @2rec: All modern development platforms support HTTP.

Comment: then it is possible for sure...

Comment: While it is possible to store images in DB, I would rather store them in file system. IMO using BLOBs makes sense only if you want your files to be accessible from multiple servers. Even on that case you could use a distributed file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. All these elements can communicate using HTTP requests. For example, the node.js/MySQL backend could generate the HTML/JS frontend usable in web browsers, while the Android app could utilize JSON API, also published by the node.js/MySQL backend.

No additional tools (languages, libraries) should be required, unless it is an application that requires specific libraries (voice recognition, for example).